# How to write this line in Latex?

Tags: verbatim

I need to write this as it is-

dec_values = libsvm.predict(x, support, sv, nsv, coeff, intercept, probA=np.empty(0), probB=np.empty(0), svm_type=0,kernel='rbf', degree=3, gamma=0.2, coef0=0, class_weight=np.empty(0), sample_weight=np.empty(0), cache_size=100)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "as it is". E.g., do you need a certain type of font, say, a mono-spaced font? Please advise.

Answer (score 8):

"as it is" is also called "verbatim". Is the following what you are aiming at? If you have more code to be included in the document, there are packages for typesetting program code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
dec_values = libsvm.predict(x, support, sv, nsv, coeff, intercept,
  probA=np.empty(0), probB=np.empty(0), svm_type=0,kernel='rbf',
  degree=3, gamma=0.2, coef0=0, class_weight=np.empty(0),
  sample_weight=np.empty(0), cache_size=100)
\end{verbatim}
In the text: \verb"x, support, sv".  Marking spaces explicitly:
\verb*"nsv, coeff, intercept" (or use the \verb"verbatim*"
environment).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the string to be typeset in a monospaced font and if you want  automatic line-breaking, I suggest you set up a dedicated environment -- called `code` in the following example -- that switches to ragged-right mode, switches to a monospaced font, and suspends the special meaning of the `_` (underscore) character. (The code shown below uses the instruction `\catcode`_=12`` to remove the special meaning of `_`; depending on your code, you may need to apply this treatment to other "special" characters, such as `#`, `&`, and `%`.)

Separately, if you want "straight" vertical quote marks, you'll also need to replace each instance of `'` with `\textquotesingle` -- and load the `textcomp` package, which provides this macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for "\textquotesingle" macro
%% Set up an environment to typeset code in-line with automatic  line-breaking
\newenvironment{code}{\raggedright\ttfamily\catcode`\_=12}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
dec_values = libsvm.predict(x, support, sv, nsv, coeff, intercept, probA=np.empty(0), probB=np.empty(0), svm_type=0, kernel='rbf', degree=3, gamma=0.2, coef0=0, class_weight=np.empty(0), sample_weight=np.empty(0), cache_size=100) 
\end{code}

\medskip
or---note shape of quotes around ``\texttt{rbf}'' substring:

\begin{code}
dec_values = libsvm.predict(x, support, sv, nsv, coeff, intercept, probA=np.empty(0), probB=np.empty(0), svm_type=0, kernel=\textquotesingle rbf\textquotesingle, degree=3, gamma=0.2, coef0=0, class_weight=np.empty(0), sample_weight=np.empty(0), cache_size=100) 
\end{code}

\end{document}
```